# Correct hyphenation of "http://" in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, hyphenation, urls

I encounter a problem with an online source in my bibliography and can't find a solution. Whereas all other sources and URLs show "perfect" hyphenation, the first line of the entry of one specific source **ends with "http:" and the new line begins with "//www."**.

In my view, the "//" should belong to "http:" and remain in the first line. **Is there a way to avoid the hyphenation within the "http://" expression?**

`mbox` did not work. I also tried `\renewcommand{\UrlBigBreaks}{\do\:\do\/}`, but that didn't change anything. Changing the `\UrlBreakPenalty` would have an impact on both : and - and thus change the hyphenation of the whole URL (and all other sources) -- and I don't want to avoid line breaks after hyphens, in general.

Do you have any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
    \documentclass[10pt, a4]{scrbook}

    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
    \usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes} 
    \usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=bibtex,urldate=comp,dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}
    \urlstyle{rm}

    \usepackage{url}

    \begin{filecontents}{demo.bib}
    @online{Demo.2015,
     author = {Dostert, Elisabeth},
     year = {2015},
     title = {\enquote{Wir machen nie das, was der Kunde sagt.}},
     url = {http://www.sueddeutsche.de/wirtschaft/was-macht-eigentlich-juergen-r-schmid-wir-machen-nie-das-was-der-kunden-sagt-1.2622207},
     urldate = {2015-10-22}
    }
    \end{filecontents}

    \bibliography{demo.bib}

    \begin{document}
        \cite{Demo.2015}
        \printbibliography
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

URL line breaking in bibliographies is notoriously hard and you will find many questions on this site about it.

In your case the ad hoc

```
\apptocmd{\biburlsetup}{\def\UrlBigBreaks{\do\:\do\-\do\/}}%
```

does the trick, the standard is `\def\UrlBigBreaks{\do\:\do\-}%`, we just added the `/` character.

The [`url` package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/url/url.pdf) says (p. 4)

> The result is that a series of consecutive `BigBreak` characters will
>   break at the end and only at the end; a series of `Break` characters
>   will break after the first and after every following pair; there will
>   be no break between a `Break` character and a following `BigBreak`
>   char; breaks are permitted when a `BigBreak` character is followed by
>   `Break` or any other char.

So with `:` and `-` in `BigBreak` and `/` in `Break`, in `http://` the `Break` character `/` follows a `BigBreak` char `:`, thus allowing a break by the last clause. But if we add `/` to `BigBreak` we can only break after `://` by the first clause.